# Eclipse not recognizing TODO/FIXME comments with Scala IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, comments, scala-ide

Comments such as `// TODO something` or `// FIXME this` used to be recognized by Eclipse and put in the Tasks view while I was using it for Java development.

I'm now writing Scala, and those comments are not recognized anymore.

- Eclipse version: Kepler SR2
- Scala IDE version: 3.0.4

How can I enable this feature?

Comment: In Eclipse you have a search option in the preference window. If there is one too in the Scala IDE, just search for Task.

Comment: @MystyxMac There is nothing related to Scala when I search "task". There are general options, though, and they are enabled.

Comment: Looks like the Scala IDE doesn't implement these (yet?). The Eclipse term for these seems to be "Task Tags", BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the task tags did work in the past but it has been broken at some point. It is still not fixed, see [this ticket](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1002137) for any progress on this feature.

Comment: One would expect such tags to be language neutral, but OK.

Comment: @nitind Can you elaborate?